# MySQL Error 1005: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I work on a database with MySQL, I have a main calendar table **date** that share some columns (year and month) with another one **astreinte_mensu**, I've created some PRIMARY KEYS succesfully but when I come to make the FOREIGN KEYS i got the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 33: Can't create table `testDB`.`astreinte_mensu`
(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Detailed error output:

```
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
```

Date table:

```
CREATE TABLE date(
   dateID int NOT NULL,
   annee int NOT NULL,
   mois int NOT NULL,
   semaine int NOT NULL,
   jour int NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT PK_date PRIMARY KEY (dateID,annee,mois,semaine,jour)
) Engine=innoDB;
```

Astreinte_mensu table:

```
CREATE TABLE astreinte_mensu(
   annee int,
   mois int,
   Personne1Nuit int,
   Personne2Nuit int,
   Personne1Jour int,
   Personne2Jour int,
   FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES date(annee),
   FOREIGN KEY (mois) REFERENCES date(mois),
   FOREIGN KEY (Personne1Nuit) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
   FOREIGN KEY (Personne2Nuit) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
   FOREIGN KEY (Personne1Jour) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
   FOREIGN KEY (Personne2Jour) REFERENCES contact(PersonID)
) Engine=innoDB;
```

I already checked that the date Table is created before the other one
and that the columns are from the same datatype.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: A foreign key must reference either a primary key or a column which has a unique constraint on it.  Your code isn't doing this, it's doing something else.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my code does that ! "annee" and "mois" columns got the PRIMARY KEY constraint (UNIQUE implicitly aswell)..

Comment: No they don't.  You added a _collective_ unique constraint on all five columns.  Not the same as an individual unique constraint.

Comment: apart from the error your table name cannot be as **date** bcoz of the date data type

Comment: @Sivabalan Weird ! i already worked with a **date** table and I hadn't any problems. Maybe because its lowercase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys in MySQL must reference a column in another table which has an index, ideally a unique index.  This usually happens when that other column is a primary key, but it can also not be a primary key so long as there is an index.  In your current code, you made a primary key out of five columns:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_date PRIMARY KEY (dateID, annee, mois, semaine, jour)
```

But all this means is that each combination of those five values *together* has to be unique.  It does not mean that any one of the columns has an index.

The immediate problem I see in your code is that you are referring to `annee` and `mois` from the `astreinte_mensu` table.  We can try adding unique constraints to these columns.  Here is a version of your code which might work:

```
CREATE TABLE date (
    dateID int NOT NULL,
    annee int NOT NULL,
    mois int NOT NULL,
    semaine int NOT NULL,
    jour int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_date PRIMARY KEY (dateID, annee, mois, semaine, jour),
    UNIQUE KEY idx_annee (annee),
    UNIQUE KEY idx_mois (mois)
) Engine=innoDB;

CREATE TABLE astreinte_mensu (
    annee int,
    mois int,
    Personne1Nuit int,
    Personne2Nuit int,
    Personne1Jour int,
    Personne2Jour int,
    FOREIGN KEY (annee) REFERENCES date(annee),
    FOREIGN KEY (mois) REFERENCES date(mois),
    FOREIGN KEY (Personne1Nuit) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Personne2Nuit) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Personne1Jour) REFERENCES contact(PersonID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Personne2Jour) REFERENCES contact(PersonID)
 ) Engine=innoDB;
```

I assume that the `contact` table has a column `PersonID` which is unique.  If not, this would be another cause of error.

Comment: Many thanks !!! It already seems clearer to me. And yes 'PersonID' got the UNIQUE constraint so everything is fine now :)

Comment: Let me know if this works.  If not, I can change it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Although your first statement describes a *best practice*, MySQL does not actually enforce it.  Any index is sufficient for a foreign key reference.  See:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24f897.  Note:  I in no way condone using non-primary keys for foreign key relationships.  I'm only pointing out that MySQL does not enforce this (although other databases do).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I didn't know this :-)  Maybe I was thinking of some other database.  Let me update.